# How to output a results in datafram format with a wrong/correct answers by group in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame with two columns. First column contains categories such as "Syestem 1", "Syestem 2", and the second column has numbers that represent the correct/wrong answers. Correct means 1, and wrong means 0.

For example:

| SYSTEM | Q1 |
| --- | --- |
| S1 | 0 |
| S1 | 1 |
| S2 | 1 |
| S2 | 0 |
| S2 | 1 |

How to write R code to produce this table below

| System | Coorect answers | Wrong answers | Total answrs |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S1 | 1 | 1 | 2 |
| S2 | 2 | 1 | 3 |

I used group by, filter, and if condition, but it seems not to be working. Please help me address this issue in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `group_by` and `summarise` you could do:

```r
dat <- data.frame(
  SYSTEM = c("S1", "S1", "S2", "S2", "S2"),
  Q1 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L)
)

library(dplyr)

dat |>
  group_by(SYSTEM) |>
  summarise(`Correct answers` = sum(Q1 == 1), `Wrong answers` = sum(Q1 == 0), `Total answers` = n())
#> # A tibble: 2 × 4
#>   SYSTEM `Correct answers` `Wrong answers` `Total answers`
#>   <chr>              <int>           <int>           <int>
#> 1 S1                     1               1               2
#> 2 S2                     2               1               3
```